# standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, gunicorn

I built and ran my dockerfile but am getting the error `standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error`. What does this mean and why is this happening per my configuration?

DOCKERFILE:

```
# 1
FROM python:3.9.2-slim

# 2
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt

# 3
COPY . /
WORKDIR /

# 4
RUN "./gunicorn.sh"
```

gunicorn.sh:

```
gunicorn "website:create_app()" -w 3 -p 5000
```

I am using `docker build -t gunicorn-flask-example .` in the directory of the dockerfile.

Comment: Can you post your run command as well?

Comment: @tentative `docker build D:\flask-app -t gunicorn-flask-example` Then I go into docker hub to run it.

Comment: If you're running `docker build` where your source code is, you should just run `docker build -t gunicorn-flask-example .`. You're not providing the build context, check [these docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description) for more information.

Comment: I used `docker build -t gunicorn-flask-example .` but got the same error. I run `docker build D:\flask-app -t gunicorn-flask-example` at _D:_, my app is at _D:\flask-app_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot to put `#!/bin/sh` on the top of 'gunicorn.sh'. Adding this line fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is change `RUN "./gunicorn.sh"` to `RUN "sh ./gunicorn.sh"`